# How do I use event handlers between JavaScript module files with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, module

I'm currently using `socket.io` to emit and listen to events between a client-side JavaScript file and a Node.js server file, but I'd like to be able to emit and listen to events between the Node server and its modules.   My thought is that it would look something like this:

Node server:

```
var module1 = require('./module1');

//Some code to launch and run the server

module1.emit('eventToModule');
module1.emit('moduleResponse', function(moduleVariable) {
   //server action based on module response
}
```

Module file:

```
var server = require('./server.js');

server.on('eventToModule', function() {
   //module response to server request
}
server.emit('moduleResponse', moduleVariable);
```

This is obviously a simplified version but I would think that this functionality should be available.  Do I need to set up the module file as a second server?  If so, what would that look like?

I also tried using `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');` (this is the code I use to allow the client to connect to the Node server) instead of `server` and had `module1` listen on and emit to `socket` but that didn't work either.

SECOND ATTEMPT (still not working):

server.js

```
//other requirements
var module1 = require('./module');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

io.on('connection', function(client) {
   client.on('emitterTester', function() {
      emitter.emit('toModule');
      emitter.on('toServer', function() {
         console.log("Emitter successful.");
      });
   });
});

module.exports = emitter;
```

module.js

```
var server1 = require('./server');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on('toModule', function() {
   console.log("Emitter heard by module.");
   emitter.emit('toServer');         
});

module.exports = emitter;
```

Also, when I try to use `server1.on`, I get the message `server1.on is not a function`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In node.js, the [`EventEmitter` object](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) is typically what you use if you want to create an object that has event listeners and can then trigger events.  You can either use the `EventEmitter` object directly or you can derive from it and create your own object that has all the `EventEmitter` functionality.

So, if you wanted to create a module that other modules could listen for events on, you would do something like this:

```
// module1.js
// module that has events

// create EventEmitter object
var obj = new EventEmitter();

// export the EventEmitter object so others can use it
module.exports = obj;

// other code in the module that does something to trigger events
// this is just one example using a timer
setInterval(function() {
    obj.emit("someEvent", someData);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Then, you could have another module that uses that first one and listens for some events coming from it:

```
// module2.js
var m1 = require('module1.js');

// register event listener
m1.on("someEvent", function(data) {
    // process data when someEvent occurs
});
```

The key points here are:

1. If you want a module to allow people to listen for events and to then trigger events, you probably want to create an `EventEmitter` object.
2. To share that `EventEmitter` object, you assign it to `module.exports` or a property of `module.exports` so that other code that does a `require()` of your module can get access to the `EventEmitter` object.
3. Once the calling code gets the `EventEmitter` object from the `require()`, it can then register to listen for events with the `.on()` method.
4. When the original module or any module wants to trigger an event, it can do so with the `.emit()` method.

---

Keep in mind that sometimes events are a great architectural choice, but not all communication between modules is best suited to events.  Sometimes, it makes sense to just export functions and allow one module to call another module's functions.  So, events are not the only way that modules can communicate with one another.

---

Your question seems to indicate that you think of socket.io as a way for two modules in the same server process to communicate.  While it might be possible to do that, that is not normally how socket.io would be used.  Usually socket.io (which is TCP/IP based) would be used for communicating between two separate processes where you do not have the luxury of making a direct function call or registering a handler for an event within your process.  These latter two schemes are typically much easier for communication within a process, whereas socket.io is more typically use for communication between processes on the same computer or between processes on different computers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's still not working for me.  I edited the original post to show the second thing I tried.

By the way, I know I can set this up just by importing the methods and using them in the server file.  I prefer to do it through events to cut down on the bulk of the server file.  Thanks.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah - You don't quite show enough code (we need to see `module.exports` in server.js), but it appears you are not exporting the EventEmitter from server.js and then using that particular eventEmitter instance in module.js.  Please see how my code example does that.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that in the first edit.  It should be right now.  Also, the events are going in both directions between the server and the module, so I'd think that whatever I have in the module, I'd need in the server and vice versa.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah - You can use one event emitter and have each side emit to that and listen to different events or each side can export their own emitter - it really depends.  If this now answers your question, you can check the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and earn yourself some reputation for following the proper procedure.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, but it's still working for me.  I tried following the code in your initial post and got the "server1.on is not a function" error (even after adding the exports - I actually had those all along but forgot to add them to the post).  The way I wrote in the edit to the original post  to try to mimic what you had written doesn't result in an error, but also doesn't work.

Comment: You aren't calling `.emit()` on the right emitter.  Since you are creating two emitters, you need to be calling `.emit()` on the other emitter (the one that the other module is listening on).  In module.js, change `emitter.emit('toServer');`  to `server1.emit('toServer');` and corresponding change in server.js.  I also see you have a circular dependency here where each module is requiring the other and using the module handle in its initialization - I'm not sure quite how node.js handles that.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah - If this answered your question, please click on the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and you will also earn a few reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: It didn't work.  I had to take a different strategy using require/export, but I couldn't get the event handling strategy to work.

Answer (score 26):

To make this easier for me, I created a new js file called `Notifier.js` which looks like this:

```
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
let notifier = new EventEmitter()
module.exports = notifier
```

When I want to use the emitter I simple require the `Notifier.js` file and access the exported value. e.g.

`randomFile.js`

```
var notifier = require('Notifier.js')
notifier.on('myEvent', (message) => {
    console.log(message)
})
```

`randomFile2.js`

```
var notifier = require('Notifier.js')
notifier.emit('myEvent', 'Test Message')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the @[Mattew Cawley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540698/matthew-cawley) response above to create this module and it work pretty well for me.

```
import EventEmitter from "events";

class Notifer {
    #eventEmitter: EventEmitter;
    #DATA_BASE_CONNECTED = "DATABASE_CONNECTED";

    constructor() {
        this.#eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    }

    emitDbConnected(args: any) {
        this.#eventEmitter.emit(this.#DATA_BASE_CONNECTED, args);
    }
    onDbConnected(handler: EventListener) {
        this.#eventEmitter.on(this.#DATA_BASE_CONNECTED, handler);
    }
}

export default new Notifer();
```

now the module can used like this:

```
// module 1

import notifier from "path/to/notifier";
notifier.emitDbConnected("some args");
```

&

```
// module 2

import notifier from "path/to/notifier";
notifier.onDbConnected((args) => {});
```