# How to emit beetween event socket.io in server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
var admin = io.of('/admin');
var user = io.of('/user');
user.on("connection", function(socket) {
     socket.on("accept-request", function(data) {
        var res = {data:"accepted" };
        admin.emit("eventone", res);
     })
});
admin.on("connection", function(socket){
  socket.on("eventone", function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

If you see, `eventone` was emitted from `user` namespace. And in `admin` namespace there will be another function or operation. I've already try this, but not working.

Is this possible to do ? 
If yes, how to do this in right ways ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help about writing questions with details we need to provide an answer. Specifically in this case, can you explain what do you mean by `not working` and what is the expected result?

Comment: Thanks, If you see, the `eventone` was emitted from `user` name space. But on `admin` namespace, it's not catch the emit from` user` name space

Comment: So can you answer this ? Rather than to advise me how to ask ? Maybe you need some reference about how to giving advise, and how to understand a question ? @MathewJibin

Comment: not possible they're diff connection(s)

Comment: You are emitting `eventone` on the server end, which will raise the event on all client ends of that connection. And your handler is on the `server end` itself, which will be not be invoked in this case.

Comment: So the conclusion is, this is impossible to do. Then how I can make a similar things like this ? So that, i can sent data between name space for other operation?

Comment: On the same server? Just make a common function and call it from wherever required?

Comment: well thanks for the comment. After search, and asking people ,I use event emitter for handling communication between event in server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this [question/asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235021/how-do-i-use-event-handlers-between-javascript-module-files-with-node-js)

I use the `events` module in node js. For communication beetwen 2 socket namespace

Example to use :

```
var events = require('events');
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var admin = io.of('/admin');
var user = io.of('/user');
user.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on("ponged", function(data){
     emitter.emit("pinged", data);
  })
});

admin.on ('connection' , function(socket) {
  emitter.on("pinged" , function(data){
     console.log(data)
  });
});
```