# Call function of JS object of a module from different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, nodejs-server

I have a architecture like this

- ```
  index.js -> server.js
  ```
- ```
  index.js -> bot.js
  ```

I have in index.js both express server and bot objects.
In index.js there are a script that access data from different api with some interval.
When frontend fetch server's endpoint of an API i want to call function of an index.js to call a function of a bot instance. Is there a npm package or some trick to throw event and catch it in outer module?

I have experience of doing like that in electron.js with Inter-Process Communication but wonder how i can do it without electron. Also I can't just create exported object from module again because it will cause polling error.

Some code to help understand what i mean:

index.js

```js
// Bot
const bot = require("./bot");

// Admin-panel
const adminPanel = require("./server");


async function start() {
    // Simplified main script
    const data = await axios.get("Some link here")
    if (data.someData == true){
         bot.sendMessage(someId,`Some message`)
    }
}
```

bot.js

```js
const TelegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.BOT_TOKEN, { polling: true });
    bot.on("message", (msg) => {
         // Some action
    }
);

bot.on("polling_error", console.log);

module.exports = bot;
```

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "public")));

app.use("/api/sendMessage", (req, res) => {
    const {message} = req.body;
    // Call bot.sendMessage(someId, message) from here
});

app.listen(5000);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you provide some code samples describing what you are attempting to do, what you have tried, and what is not working as expected?

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas updated question with some sample data

Answer (score 0):

For those who wondering, this may be your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958272/23296640 
https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/the-nodejs-event-emitter